# How to display number of iframes (youtube embed) the user want to see with js

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, iframe

I have to do a school project where i use some while loops (js) in a website.
I have a page where i want to show youtube videos (website is on a friend who do slam and storytelling on scene).
The idea was to put a button, calling a function who begin with  a prompt asking the user to put a number (between 1 - 13 since i have 13 videos). Then create elements to be stocked in an array, and a while loop pushing those elements in the array, which will be append to a div in my html page.

I know it's far from clean, i'm starting there. Any ideas on how i could do something close with base js?  Thanks a lot :)

```
function iframes(){

    var nbvideos = prompt("How many videos you want? Between 1 and 13.");
    console.log(nbvideos)


    var video1 = document.createElement("iframe");
    video1.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bbk4VccQgG0";
    video1.setAttribute.boxShadow= "1px 1px 1px 1px";
    video1.setAttribute.fontWeight= "500";
    video1.setAttribute.margin= "15px";
    video1.setAttribute.width= "560";
    video1.setAttribute.height= "315";
    video1.setAttribute.frameborder= "0";
    video1.setAttribute.effectAllowed = "accelerometer", "autoplay", "encrypted-media", "gyroscope", "picture-in-picture";
    video1.setAttribute.textContent= "Soirée solo";
    video1.setAttribute.id = "t1";
    video1.style.display = "inline-block";
    var video2 = document.createElement("iframe").src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/uQbn5nOkiMU";
    video2.setAttribute.boxShadow= "1px 1px 1px 1px";
    video2.setAttribute.fontWeight= "500";
    video2.setAttribute.margin= "15px";
    video2.setAttribute.width= "560";
    video2.setAttribute.height= "315";
    video2.setAttribute.frameborder= "0";
    video2.setAttribute.effectAllowed = "accelerometer", "autoplay", "encrypted-media", "gyroscope", "picture-in-picture";
    video2.setAttribute.textContent= "Soirée solo";
    video2.setAttribute.id = "t2";
    video2.style.display = "inline-block";
    var video3 = document.createElement("iframe").src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/5jDp8wNjVbM";
    video3.setAttribute.boxShadow= "1px 1px 1px 1px";
    video3.setAttribute.fontWeight= "500";
    video3.setAttribute.margin= "15px";
    video3.setAttribute.width= "560";
    video3.setAttribute.height= "315";
    video3.setAttribute.frameborder= "0";
    video1.setAttribute.effectAllowed = "accelerometer", "autoplay", "encrypted-media", "gyroscope", "picture-in-picture";
    video3.setAttribute.textContent= "A la bonne place";
    video3.setAttribute.id = "t3";
    video3.style.display = "inline-block";


    var tableau = [video1,video2,video3] //tableau contenant les variables videos
    var i = 0;

        while(i <= nbvideos){
            var videos = tableau [i]
            var grilleVideos = document.getElementById("grille");
            grilleVideos.appendChild(videos);
            compteur ++

        }

//boutonvideos
var boutonvid = document.getElementById("boutonVideos");
boutonvid.addEventListener ("click", iframes );
```

Comment: Good start! What do you mean by "with base js"?

Comment: I mean basic js. No libraries or too advance code. I started the journey 1 month ago, so the school project needs to be "simple", containing what we learned so far.

Comment: Gotcha! It looks like you've got your answer below, just want to point out one thing. If you want to try to get the code down in size a bit, you could have a list of YouTube embed URLs (or ven IDs), then generate the elements on the fly. Since all the attributes are the same, you could create the element inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo, french here too :p

Some changes I made

1. Adding a ***clear the div "grille"*** when you ask number of videos you want to show because if the customer click a second time to show a number of videos it would just append more videos and not remove the others load before.
2. Your array need no space between the name and the identifier. So "tableau [i]" have to be "tableau[i]"
3. You don't need "setAttribute" since it's a property of the iframe, using "setAttribute" would not work
4. In your loop to check how many video you want to show you call a variable "compteur" but you mean "i" since it's the one that increment each time.

So here is the code bellow :)

```js
function iframes(){
  
  document.getElementById("grille").innerHTML = ""

    var nbvideos = prompt("How many videos you want? Between 1 and 13.");
    console.log(nbvideos)


    var video1 = document.createElement("iframe");
    video1.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bbk4VccQgG0";
    video1.boxShadow= "20px 1px 1px 1px";
      video1.fontWeight= "500";
      video1.margin= "15px";
      video1.width= "560";
      video1.height= "315";
      video1.frameborder= "0";
      video1.effectAllowed = "accelerometer", "autoplay", "encrypted-media", "gyroscope", "picture-in-picture";
      video1.textContent= "Soirée solo";
      video1.setAttribute.id = "t1";
      video1.style.display = "inline-block";
  
  var video2 = document.createElement("iframe")
    video2.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/uQbn5nOkiMU";
    video2.boxShadow= "1px 1px 1px 1px";
    video2.fontWeight= "500";
    video2.margin= "15px";
    video2.width= "560";
    video2.height= "315";
    video2.frameborder= "0";
    video2.effectAllowed = "accelerometer", "autoplay", "encrypted-media", "gyroscope", "picture-in-picture";
    video2.textContent= "Soirée solo";
    video2.id = "t2";
    video2.style.display = "inline-block";
  
    var video3 = document.createElement("iframe")
    video3.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/5jDp8wNjVbM";
    video3.boxShadow= "1px 1px 1px 1px";
    video3.fontWeight= "500";
    video3.margin= "15px";
    video3.width= "560";
    video3.height= "315";
    video3.frameborder= "0";
    video1.effectAllowed = "accelerometer", "autoplay", "encrypted-media", "gyroscope", "picture-in-picture";
    video3.textContent= "A la bonne place";
    video3.id = "t3";
    video3.style.
lay = "inline-block";
    

    var tableau = [video1,video2,video3] //tableau contenant les variables videos
    var i = 1;

        while(i <= nbvideos){
          document.getElementById("grille").appendChild(tableau[i-1]);
          i++
        }
}

//boutonvideos
var boutonvid = document.getElementById("boutonVideos");
boutonvid.addEventListener ("click", iframes );
```

```html
<input type="button" id="boutonVideos" value="Afficher des vidéos">
<div id="grille"></div>
```

Comment: Un ENORME merci :)

Comment: yeah i changed my variable "compteur" to "i" since i was publishing in english, forgot on piece :/

Comment: I'm trying to take 1 off i variable (its showing 3 videos when i ask 2 for ex). I though i could just do that : document.getElementById("grille").appendChild(tableau[i-1]);

Comment: Indeed, I updated the code to fix that, you need to update the variable **i** too so it start at 1 and not 0 because then the first iteration would be 0-1 and there is no object at the position -1 :)

Comment: Yeah i figured :) Its working great. Thanks again, that helped a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you mean by base js but if you are asking for how to optimise the above code. then you can wrap repeating iframe generation code inside one method. as follows

```
let videosList = [{
  no: 1,
  url: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bbk4VccQgG0'
},
{
  no: 2,
  url: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/uQbn5nOkiMU'
},
{
  no: 3,
  url: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/5jDp8wNjVbM'
}];

function generateIFrame(video) {
  var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
  frame.src = video.url;
  frame.setAttribute.boxShadow= "1px 1px 1px 1px";
  frame.setAttribute.fontWeight= "500";
  frame.setAttribute.margin= "15px";
  frame.setAttribute.width= "560";
  frame.setAttribute.height= "315";
  frame.setAttribute.frameborder= "0";
  frame.setAttribute.effectAllowed = "accelerometer", "autoplay", "encrypted-media", "gyroscope", "picture-in-picture";
  frame.setAttribute.textContent= "Soirée solo";
  frame.setAttribute.id = "t1";
  frame.style.display = "inline-block";
  return frame;
}

function iframes() {
  var nbvideos = prompt("How many videos you want? Between 1 and 13.");
  console.log(nbvideos)
  var grilleVideos = document.getElementById("grille");
  for(let i = 0, l = (nbvideos < videosList.length) ? nbvideos : videosList.length; i < l; i++) {
    grilleVideos.appendChild(generateIFrame(videosList[i]));
  }
}

iframes();
```

you can do something like this [here](https://syncfiddle.net/fiddle/-Lv9NAbR8CWltjFyYnEO)